# Looping through array to count in mongodb/mongoose

Tags: arrays, mongodb, loops, mongoose

I have a user schema that contains a value called amputationInfo:

```
amputationInfo: [
      {
        type: String,
      },
    ],
```

Here is an example of what that might look like in the database:

```
amputationInfo: [
 "Double Symes/Boyd", 
  "Single Above-Elbow"
]
```

I have a review Schema that allows a user to leave a review, it contains a reference to the user who left it:

```
user: {
  type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
  ref: 'User',
  require: [true, 'Each review must have an associated user!'],
},
```

When a user leaves a review, I want to create an aggregate function that looks up the user on the review, finds their amputationInfo, loops through the array and adds up the total amount of users that contain `"Double Symes/Boyd", "Single Above-Elbow"`

So if we have 3 users and their amputationInfo is as follows:

```
 amputationInfo: [
  "Double Symes/Boyd", 
  "Single Above-Elbow"
 ]

amputationInfo: [ 
  "Single Above-Elbow"
]

amputationInfo: []
```

The return from the aggregate function will count each term and add one to the corresponding value and look something like this:

```
[
 {
    doubleSymesBoyd: 1,
    singleAboveElbow: 2
  }
]
```

Here is what I have tried, but I just don't know enough about mongoDB to solve the issue:

```
[
  {
    '$match': {
      'prosthetistID': new ObjectId('6126ca6148f34c00189f86f5')
    }
  }, {
    '$lookup': {
      'from': 'users', 
      'localField': 'user', 
      'foreignField': '_id', 
      'as': 'userInfo'
    }
  }, {
    '$unwind': {
      'path': '$userInfo'
    }
  }
]
```

After the $unwind, the resulting object has a userInfo key, that contains an amputationInfo array nested:

[image: Explainer picture]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have following stages

- `$unwind` to deconstruct the array
- first `$group` to get the sum of each category
- second `$group` to push into one document and make it as key value pair
- `$arrayToObject` to get the desired output
- `$replaceRoot` to make the data output into root

Here is the code

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$unwind": "$userInfo.amputationInfo" },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$userInfo.amputationInfo",
      "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      data: { $push: {
          k: "$_id",
          v: "$count"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { $project: { data: { "$arrayToObject": "$data" } } },
  { "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": "$data" } }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/26tngXAkBW-)**

Comment: Ok that is exactly as I was looking for. To take this further...what if I wanted the output to be an array like [{Single Above-Elbow: 2, Double Symes/Boyd: 2}] to sort by the largest value?

Comment: @klaurtar1 But these are key value pair where keys are unique. So I dont think (Im not sure) there is a method to sort inside object, but you can sort inside array like https://mongoplayground.net/p/gIrVtfQmHAC